# How to get User-Defined variables in node-red app in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

In my node-red app in Bluemix, I added a User-Defined environment variable.
Not sure how to get that variable from a function in my node-red application.
Thanks.

Comment: We need more context, where do you want to use  the environment variable?

Comment: @hardillb I want to use the environment variable in a function in my node-red app

Comment: I've added a comment to the other answer to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the bluemix-settings.js file to include the "process" built-n or other variables in functionGlobalContext.

functionGlobalContext: {
     process: process
 }

Once redeployed you can access the process in a function node as...

context.global.process

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/170246/how-do-i-get-at-my-vcap-variables-from-node-red.html

Comment: I did the above and then printed the context.global.process to the console from my node-red flow.  There is a lot of information that printed but I do not see my user-defined variable.

Comment: `context.process` is a complex object, you only need `context.process.env['ENV_VAR_NAME']` to get access to the environment variable you want

Answer (score 0):

To get User Defined Variable from Bluemix you must use something like this:

```
var services = context.global.process.env['USR_DEFINED_VAR'];
```

after configuring `functionGlobalContext: { process: process }` in  bluemix-settings.js

To change the value is just like that:

```
context.global.process.env['USR_DEFINED_VAR'] = value;
```